# Apache WampServer - Getting "It works!" only with https

Tags: apache-2.4, localhost

I am using WampServer 3.2.3 (Apache 2.4.46) and I added an SSL certificate on a virtual host, but when I go to this virtual host's whebsite with **http**, it displays the configured page.
The problem is that when I go with **https**, the website shows the default page "It works!".

I searched for "htdocs" (the path where the file is stored) in httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf, but I don't have any result.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: It sounds like you see the default virtualhost and need to create a SSL VirtualHost in addition to the plain http VirtualHost that is configured for your content.

Comment: We consider this setup unsuitable as business practice (so this is offtopic). Also it was already answered, why this is bad. If you are setting up a developer/test station, better ask on webmasters.